# Set the CALayer 'borderWidth' and 'cornerRadius' in iOS, can not fully covers background

Tags: ios, calayer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.yuanjiao.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.yuanjiao.layer.cornerRadius = self.yuanjiao.frame.size.width/2;
    self.yuanjiao.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.yuanjiao.layer.borderWidth = 5;
    self.yuanjiao.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1].CGColor;

    //    self.yuanjiao.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    //    self.yuanjiao.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
    //    self.yuanjiao.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    //    self.yuanjiao.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
}
```

Effect：

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/alPDr.png]

Border not fully cover the the background.

Setting shadowxxx has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour of layer's property. If you look at [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/borderWidth) for `borderWidth` property, you will find: -

> **Discussion**
>   When this value is greater than 0.0, the layer draws a border using the current borderColor value. The border is drawn inset from the receiver’s bounds by the value specified in this property. **It is composited above the receiver’s contents and sublayers and includes the effects of the cornerRadius property.**
>
> The default value of this property is 0.0.

If you are in need to fill the `borderWidth` portion with `blackColor` as well, then you have two choices

1. There is no point in having a border whose color is not different than the content of view. You will not be able to see the border at all. All you will see is a little bigger circle filled with `blackColor`.
2. If you wanna keep border and also needs to fill it with black color then assign the `borderColor` property to `blackColor`.

Comment: border and view Why not entirely overlap?

Comment: @Tyler - That's how it is designed. Check the bold section of documentation reference. If `borderWidth>0` then border will be drawn outwards of View layer touching at each point.